# No error message displayed in my View from controller

Tags: laravel

I am trying to display the error msg but it's not displaying. I can see the error msg in the console (Network tab) but nothing in the view.
Thanks in advance.

the output from the API.

```
{"message":"The given data was invalid.","errors":{"title":["The title field is required."]}}
```

controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        "title"=> "required"
    ]);
    try {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            $request->merge(['created_by_user_info_id' => Auth::user()->id]);
            SavingTypes::create($request->all());
            $data['status'] = true;
            $data['title'] = null;
            $data['message'] = 'Added Successfully.';
        }
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $data['status'] = false;
        $data['message'] = 'Something went wrong. please try again';
        $data['error'] = $e->getMessage();
    }
    return $data;
}
```

View:

```
<h1>{{ $errors->first('title') }}test</h1> // only the "test" is visible and theres no error msg although I can see the error msg in the console (Network tab)
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="title" name="title" >
```

Comment: are you submiting the form through ajax ?

Comment: You are getting the response is json (calling ajax request maybe), then you need to show errors from ajax method from the front itself when you make the ajax call, It will be better if you provide more information as you are using `if($request->ajax())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If request send through AJAX then you can't access like

```
$errors->first('title')
```

You will get errors inside your JavaScript

```
$.ajax({

    // some code
    
    
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // Here you will get errors
        console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
});
```